# How can I make scrapy check for a field and ignore searching the link

Tags: scrapy, screen-scraping, scraper, parsel

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request


class SunBizSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'sunbiz'
start_urls = ['http://search.sunbiz.org/Inquiry/CorporationSearch/SearchResults?inquiryType=EntityName&searchNameOrder=A&searchTerm=a']

def parse(self, response):
    leurl = 'http://search.sunbiz.org'
    next_plis = response.xpath("//div[@class='navigationBar'][1]//a[@title='Next List']/@href").extract()
    next_lis = (leurl+ ', '.join(next_plis))
    yield scrapy.Request(next_lis, callback=self.parse)
    for href in response.css('.large-width a::attr(href)'):
        full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_biz)

def parse_biz(self, response):
    re1='((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])' #        MMDDYYYY 1
    date = response.xpath('//span').re_first(re1)
    yield {
        'Name': response.css('.corporationName span::text').extract()[1],
        'Date': date,
        'Link': response.url,
        }
```

Regular expression would most likely find the words inact and cross reff
[image: What i want the scrawler not to check is in highlight]

As you can see above I highlighted words such as `inact`, `name hs` and `cross rf` which are the items I want the crawler to check for and not do anything if it has those words.

Comment: <td class="small-width">INACT</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `xpath` selector to check inner text, so if you want to get all the `td` with inner text `Active`, use something like:

```
response.xpath('//td[text()="Active"]')
```

The same for other strings, you could also use:

```
response.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "Activ")]')
```

if  you only want one part of the string

Comment: So i would make an if statement, to check if response.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "Activ")]') is not null and then pasrse the page if it passes the arguments